# MockK throws ExceptionInInitializerError when running Android Tests on Emulator from Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-emulator, mockk

I've written some Android Tests (instrumented) for our Kotlin + Compose project. They heavily rely on MockK for mocking/stubbing. I'm trying to run the tests from the CLI (using Gradle), so I can hook it up to some CI/CD pipeline.

When I run the tests using Gradle (from the IDE or CLI) against an emulated device, all tests using MockK fail with a ExceptionInInitializerError.
Looking closer at the error I see:

```
Caused by: io.mockk.proxy.MockKAgentException: MockK could not self-attach a jvmti agent to the current VM. This feature is required for inline mocking.
This error occured due to an I/O error during the creation of this agent: java.io.IOException: Unable to dlopen libmockkjvmtiagent.so: dlopen failed: "/data/app/~~32zSVIoibe92TijCTt4JEA==/com.ybvr.ybvrandroidwhitelabel.test-zIkEFUEMnG9CVRsul8D8og==/lib/x86/libmockkjvmtiagent.so" is for EM_386 (3) instead of EM_ARM (40)
```

What doesn't make any sense to me is that the error seems to be complaining about the library not being ARM, but x86, when the emulated device is actually an x86 (running Windows).

Running all tests from the IDE (Android Studio) on emulator and real device pass without any issue (using the run configurations menu).
Running the tests from CLI using Gradle on a real device pass without any issue (Pixel 6a - Android 14).

I was expecting the tests to pass when running the tests on the emulated device from Gradle. I've tried with several versions of the Android SDK to no avail.

build.gradle:

```
android
{
defaultConfig {
...
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
}
...

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

testOptions {
    packagingOptions { jniLibs { useLegacyPackaging = true } }
    execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
}
}
dependencies{

androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-android:1.13.7"
androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-agent-jvm:1.13.7"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.2'
androidTestUtil "androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.2"
}
```